# What is the Id needed in options.ids for method loadFile(url,options, ...)

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We start using Forge API to load .rvt files in the Forge Viewer and we are looking for a way to load only specific list of elements.

The method loadFile(url, options, ....) with the field options.ids specified seems to be the solution to our problem (isn't it ?).

We tried different ids but none of them works :

In Revit we have an element with `id = 1426299`, so we tried :

*int or decimal string with and without padding :*

```
- options.ids = 1426299<br/>
- options.ids = "1426299"<br/>
- options.ids = 01426299<br/>
- options.ids = "01426299"<br/>
```

*in hexadecimal with and without padding :*

```
- options.ids = "15c37b"<br/>
- options.ids = "0015c37b"<br/>
- options.ids = "15C37B"<br/>
- options.ids = "0015C37B"<br/>
- options.ids = "0015C37B"<br/>
```

*with GUID find in object_ids.json.gz :*

- `options.ids = "2a4577e1-1534-4806-85f3-3f29d53053eb-0015c37b"`

In the example of the doc (here : https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/document/ ), the id is "XXX02UUEs", we can't figure out where we can find this type of ids. it's seems to be a specific id for the viewer, but where can I access it ?

Thks for your help !

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to load only some specific Ids upon initial load of your model. I'm curious where did you see the "options.ids" field was used? Did you see that by looking in the viewer source code? I couldn't see such options on my side. The suggested workaround would be to hide the model until it has been fully loaded (for example with an overlay div), hide the unwanted node Ids and display it to user.

Comment: Ok... the getItemById you are referring to is actually returning a viewable item, from the whole model, not a component inside a loaded design. This is a bit confusing: a URN give you access to a specific model, which can be composed of 1 or several viewable paths (eg RVT documents with 2D + 3D views). What you load in the viewer is a viewable path, the viewer will then download the relevant resources and build the design components affecting dbIds on the fly. There is unfortunately no way to customize that process at the moment before the design is fully loaded.

Comment: Of course you could rewrite the loading mechanism, but that would be quite a bit of rework I suppose. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for fast answer and good explanation. Ok now I understand the concept of viewable and viewable id. I hope the possibility to load from the server only specific elements will be available in the futur. It could be great to load only elements in a specific bbox to have a quick render.

Comment: Agreed, I'm not sure if this is easily feasible technically, but I will log that as a wish ...

Answer (score 0):

The getItemById you are referring to is actually returning a viewable item, from the whole model, not a component inside a loaded design.

This is a bit confusing:

A URN give you access to a specific model, which can be composed of 1 or several viewable paths (eg RVT documents with 2D + 3D views). What you load in the viewer is a viewable path, the viewer will then download the relevant resources and build the design components affecting dbIds on the fly. There is unfortunately no way to customize that process at the moment before the design is fully loaded.